# Android "mmap failed: Out of memory" with large APK

Tags: android, memory, crash, mmap

My Android app APK is fairly large at ~480 MB.  I can install the app just fine but on Android OS 2.2 when the app is launched I get this error (in logcat):

```
09-21 00:04:12.855: W/dalvikvm(3178): mmap(480331001, RO, FILE|SHARED, 28, 0) failed: Out of memory
09-21 00:04:12.855: W/dalvikvm(3178): Map of '/data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-1.apk' failed
09-21 00:04:12.855: D/AndroidRuntime(3178): Shutting down VM
09-21 00:04:12.855: W/dalvikvm(3178): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d828)
09-21 00:04:12.859: E/AndroidRuntime(3178): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-21 00:04:12.859: E/AndroidRuntime(3178): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity 
...
```

This does not happen on OS 4.0+.  Some users are reporting a crash on startup in 2.3.4 and 2.3.7, which I suspect is the same problem.  Why is mmap failing on my APK?

**EDIT**: I know the app is very large (it's a game with lots of assets) and the Play Store limits APKs to 50 MB, but this is for a carrier in another country that has no APK size limit.  I already have a version of the app on the Play Store with an APK of ~20MB that makes use of expansion files which exhibits no mmap problems.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how are you consuming almost half a gig of space with your app?

Comment: Ow, ow, my RAM hurts. Move the stuff away from the APK, and download it on first run, or partition and download pieces on demand. What is it, may I ask? An offline phonebook? A HD movie?

Comment: The app is a game, with lots of assets.  Shouldn't the size of the APK be independent of how much memory (RAM) it consumes?  The APK is mmap'ed which should mean that the address space it takes up in virtual memory is backed by the filesystem and not memory, right?  This "mmap out of memory" issue happens before I do a single "new" in Java or "malloc" in C (I make use of JNI).

Comment: Just a side-note: You can only upload APKs in 50MB increments to the Play Store. If you intend to use it, you will want to split it up into [expansion APKs](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html).

Comment: I do have a version of the app that makes use of expansion files for the Play Store, but this particular build is for another carrier's store in another country that doesn't have APK size limits (and no expansion file option either).

On a side note, the version on the play store with an APK size of ~20 MB that makes use of expansion files has no mmap problems.

Comment: Did you managed to get to the bottom of mmap issue? I am having similar problems here with mmap and was wondering if you know if this is android bad mmap implementation or something on the application side?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but on first run try copying the file to user memory, then mapping it from there.